# ip to location script not accurate

Tags: javascript, php, ip

I need to get the location of user as accurate as possible for that I am using this code

```
<script>
$.get("http://ipinfo.io/json", function(response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html(response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
</script>
```

but the problem with this is that it is not accurate it tells my IP as if I am in Madhya Pradesh but I am in Delhi at some other location I tried it is right but I think when this script could not track the location it gives anything...

I dont know what is the issue may be it is giving the location of ISP not the users location

I want the most accurate location of user as google gives is this possible please help

basically this code gives me location of ISP not the users i want location of user not their ISP

Comment: it returns an approximate location of isp. i'm now somewhere at `41°21', 48°32'` but it shows:  `39.37, 49.25` which is closer to my service provider coordinates.

Comment: is there any more accurate script or php lib

Comment: you are at the mercy of whatever the isp provides to that service

Comment: @sonamSharma as @charlietfi noticed it doesn't depend on `ip to geolocation` services. they identify you by your public ip, and in most cases this ip belongs to service providers. they rent you the ip address for a while. and moreover, their data centers may or may not be in the same geographical location with customers.

Comment: yes !!! this is the reason why i am getting location of datacenter not user's location